# JavaScript type not defined message

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Here is a snippet of my code; it is from an HTML form page:

```
Phone Number:<input type="text" id="Phone" name="Phone" onkeyup="checkFirst();" /><br />

<p id="rabbit"></p> <!-- for testing -->
```

This is the input text field and I want to call upon my `checkFirst` function which is in the head section of the html, here is my `checkFirst` function

```
<script type="text/javasciprt">
        document.getElementById("rabbit").innerHTML = "When";
        function checkFirst(){
            var numbers = 3; //document.getElementById("Phone").value.length;
            document.getElementById("rabbit").innerHTML="Hello";
            
            if (numbers <= 3) {
                document.Phone.focus();
            } else {
                document.info_open.focus();
            }
        }
</script>
```

When I run this the, nothing happens to the element with the ip "rabbit". it does not change. I ran it with the Chrome debugger and it showed in the right hand panel that I have a reference error under which it says:

> type: "not_defined"

The error is on the line of the element for phone input, why am I getting this error? I thought I defined type as 'text'.

Comment: did you mean text/javascript  instead of text/javasciprt ?

Comment: You're misinterpreting `type: "not_defined"`. It's saying the type of error is `not_defined`; it is a `not_defined` error. The `type` attribute of the `input` is just fine.

Comment: If this is a direct copy from your code, you've misspelled JavaScript.

Comment: it seems to be working http://jsbin.com/utegan/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
<script type="text/javasciprt">
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

Because the code runs perfectly in jsfiddle ( http://jsfiddle.net/yhFfc/ ).